# mysql datatable.net totalling of a rows values not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Using Mysql I need to calculate the total of values on a given row, my attempts to do this have failed with unusual results, one row working and others showing no total data. This call is in reference to a previous call answered by scaisEdge, with thanks.

[mysql how to display values on one row for each portfolio, stock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55551952/mysql-how-to-display-values-on-one-row-for-each-portfolio-stock)

I am getting values in the output but only for one row, so it is not behaving as I would expect.

```
$rows = $wpdb->get_results("
select  
t.Symbol AS Symbol
, t.Portfolio AS Portfolio
  , max(Janx) AS Janx
  , max(Febx) AS Febx
  , max(Marx) AS Marx
... etc.
  , max(Decx) AS Decx
  , (
    max(Janx) 
  + max(Febx) 
  + max(Decx) 
    ) AS Total
from  (
  SELECT
  s.symbol AS Symbol,
  p.code AS Portfolio,
  (case when ANY_VALUE(DATE_FORMAT(d.pdate,'%b')) = 'Jan' then 
 IFNULL(CEILING((SUM(IF(t.transaction_type='Buy',t.quantity,t.quantity 
    * -1)) * ANY_VALUE(d.dividend) ) / 100),0) end) AS Janx,
      (case when ANY_VALUE(DATE_FORMAT(d.pdate,'%b')) = 'Feb' then 

 IFNULL(CEILING((SUM(IF(t.transaction_type='Buy',t.quantity,t.quantity * 
-1)) * ANY_VALUE(d.dividend) ) / 100),0) end) AS Febx,
  (case when ANY_VALUE(DATE_FORMAT(d.pdate,'%b')) = 'Mar' then 
 IFNULL(CEILING((SUM(IF(t.transaction_type='Buy',t.quantity,t.quantity * -1)) * ANY_VALUE(d.dividend) ) / 100),0) end) AS Marx,
... etc 
(case when ANY_VALUE(DATE_FORMAT(d.pdate,'%b')) = 'Dec' then
IFNULL(CEILING((SUM(IF(t.transaction_type='Buy',t.quantity,t.quantity * -1)) * ANY_VALUE(d.dividend) ) / 100),0) end) AS Decx

  FROM dm_transactions t
  INNER JOIN dm_dividends d ON (d.stock_id = t.stock_id)
  INNER JOIN dm_stocks s ON (s.id = t.stock_id) 
  INNER JOIN dm_portfolios p ON (t.portfolio_id = p.id)
  WHERE ANY_VALUE(d.pdate) >= CURDATE()
  AND 
  t.user_id >= IF($user_id=4,2,$user_id)
  AND
  t.user_id <= IF($user_id=4,3,$user_id)
  GROUP BY    s.symbol,d.pdate
) t
GROUP BY   t.Symbol, t.Portfolio
... etc.

foreach ($rows as $row ){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>$row->Portfolio</td>";
echo "<td>$row->Symbol</td>";
echo "<td>$row->Janx</td>";
... etc.
echo "<td>$row->Decx</td>";
echo "<td>$row->Total</td>";
```

The total values are not summating correctly, some rows show no totals values, when there is data, my SQL query must be incorrect I suspect. All other aspects of my report are working.

Hopefully a simple error on my part.

Many Thanks in advance

Colin

Comment: I may be making some progress   ( max(Mayx) + max(Sepx) ) AS Total calculates the correct total in several rows but evaluates to 0 for others where there are values in max(Mayx) and/or max(Sepx). If I add a WHERE clause to only include a single failing row it results in no value for the Total, I will continue investigating with debug thanks Colin

Comment: I think the blank values in the rows are NULL, not displaying as such, so if I try and add a column value say max(Mayx) + max(Sepx) if max(Mayx) is empty or NULL it fails, so need to ensure NULL values are set to ZERO I think !!!

Answer (score 0):

My IFNULL expression was not positioned in the MySQL statement correctly, the revised IFNULL statement is shown below

```
  SELECT
  ANY_VALUE(s.symbol) AS Symbol,
  ANY_VALUE(p.code) AS Portfolio,
  IFNULL((case when ANY_VALUE(DATE_FORMAT(d.pdate,'%b')) = 'Jan' then CEILING((SUM(IF(t.transaction_type='Buy',t.quantity,t.quantity * -1)) * ANY_VALUE(d.dividend) ) / 100) end),0) AS Janx,
  IFNULL((case when ANY_VALUE(DATE_FORMAT(d.pdate,'%b')) = 'Feb' then CEILING((SUM(IF(t.transaction_type='Buy',t.quantity,t.quantity * -1)) * ANY_VALUE(d.dividend) ) / 100) end),0) AS Febx,
```

Thanks Colin